# asp.net C# Request.QueryString["sms"] + sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.querystring

my client have 2 server and from first server then want to send a request with some parameters and the second server take those parameters with get method, the problem is when the request come there is a + sign in it for e.g in blood group its A+, B+, O+

The data is coming fine but when I am inserting the record its removing + sign from it.

how can I get it done, as there is some space between them.

get method

> http://domain.com/join.aspx?msid=238487987328&sms=Peter
>   D 23 O+ Indiana

when I am getting it with Request.QueryString["sms"] its removing + sign

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [URL encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) the parameters (or rather, the whole URL).

Answer (score 1):

The `+` sign is the encoded version of a space, and therefore need [URL Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) to preserve it.

In fact, you need to URL Encode any URL passed parameters, make a note for the future!

Answer (score 0):

Encode `+` sign then add it to your query string